# Style is not being applied except for the first row from sql query in html code

Tags: php, html, css

I'm retrieving all the rows from sql database through a query, and i'm using a loop to get all the rows
I have a style.css file which i'm specifying a style for the , however, only the first row is receiving the style and the style is not being applied to the rest.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<head>
    <title>IIACSS search center</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
<label>Search</label>
<input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data",'root','admin123');
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$str = $_POST["search"];
$sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE question LIKE '%$str%'");

$sth->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
$sth -> execute();
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>Sample</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
  for ($a=0;$row = $sth->fetch();$a++) {
  ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->Proj_Name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->Question;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->sample;?></td>
            <br><br>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
  }
  }
  ?>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  color: black;

}

td {
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
th {
  color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a CSS problem, it is because you are closing your `</table>` in the loop, so it is ending your table after the first `tr`.

Just remove it from the loop:

```php
<?php
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data",'root','admin123');
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$str = $_POST["search"];
$sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE question LIKE '%$str%'");

$sth->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
$sth -> execute();
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>Sample</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
  for ($a=0;$row = $sth->fetch();$a++) {
  ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->Proj_Name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->Question;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->sample;?></td>
            <br><br>
        </tr>

    <?php
  } ?>
      </table>
  <?php }
  ?>
```